# Filter data by category

Tags: javascript, laravel

I have a javascript function that filters categories. There is also interleaving of lists in php.blade.

The problem is that alternation only works when filtering has All, and when we select a specific category, alternation does not work. How can this be fixed?

### JavaScript

```
$('.category-filter_item').click(function(){
    $('.category-filter_item').removeClass('active')
    $(this).addClass('active')
    var dataFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('.blog-list').hide()
    $(dataFilter).show()
})
```

### php.blade

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
<div class="category-filter" id="filter">
    <div class="category-filter_item active" data-filter="*">All</div>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
    <div class="category-filter_item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->title }}</div>
    @endforeach
</div>

@foreach ($blogs as $index => $blog)
    <div class="blog-list">
        @if ($index % 2 === 1)  //Alternation
            <div class="blog blog--left" >
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @else

            <div class="blog blog--right">
                <h2 class="blog_title">{{ $blog->title }}</h2>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endsection
```

### Controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $blogs = Blog::all();
        $categories = Category:all();

        return view('blog', compact('blogs', 'categories'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create two separate `div` for left and right posts
just make a single `div` and style that as below

```
.post { /* right post styling here */ }
.post:nth-child(odd) { /* left post styling here */ }
```

You can change the left and right position according to your need

```css
.post { 
    background: green;
    text-align: right;
}
.post:nth-child(odd) { 
    background: red; 
    text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-list">
            <div class="post" >
                <h2 class="post_title">post 1</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="post_title">post 2</h2>
            </div>
              <div class="post">
                <h2 class="post_title">post 3</h2>
            </div>
             <div class="post" >
                <h2 class="post_title">post 4</h2>
            </div>

            <div class="post">
                <h2 class="post_title">post 5</h2>
            </div>
              <div class="post">
                <h2 class="post_title">post 6</h2>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just have for the left and right post, there will be more additional <div> that will be slightly different, and so thanks for the answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` to select the relevant `.post-list` container, and then hide the relevant side:

```css
.post-list:nth-child(even) .post-left,
.post-list:nth-child(odd) .post-right {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="post post-left">
    <h2 class="post_title">L1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="post post-right">
    <h2 class="post_title">R1</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="post post-left">
    <h2 class="post_title">L2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="post post-right">
    <h2 class="post_title">R2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="post-list">
  <div class="post post-left">
    <h2 class="post_title">L3</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="post post-right">
    <h2 class="post_title">R3</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked) but only I have a category filter on the page, which is implemented in js, and when I select a category, this alternation does not work

Comment: @Kim2000 I'm afraid I can't help with that without more information. Does the category filter change the HTML structure?

Comment: I will now complete my topic

Comment: look, I use post-list show and hide there, and in the end, alternation only works for all

Comment: are you here? )